# How Do i Prevent CSS Styles from Affecting All Sites

Tags: css, firefox, styles, stylish

I got a problem with Firefox browser when applying CSS styles to websites. I use Stylesheet also. Below the rules for the PlayStore and Craigslist. They work on the intended sites but they also work globally, affecting all sites I visit. How do I rescrict them to just the PlayStore and Craigslist without affecting other site?

**@-moz-document url-prefix("https://play.google.com/store"){**

**@-moz-document url-prefix("http://newyork.craigslist.org"),   domain(craigslist.org){**

It seems to me that the 2 words within each web address separated by a period in the rule may be the problem, like, "play.store" and newyork.craigslist". I say this because I use other styles with only "one" word in its rule and they work without affecting other sites.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have to specify domain as well

```css
@-moz-document domain('images.example.com'), url-prefix('http://example.com/images') {
```

https://github.com/JasonBarnabe/stylish/wiki/Applying-styles-to-specific-sites